# Spring , How to have Swagger UI send a request without Hypertext Transfer Protocol

Tags: java, spring, swagger

Is there a possibility to instruct Swagger not to send the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (http) in front of a POST or GET request  ?

As you can see on the screenshot, the **Request URL** is using http protocol

The reason of my question is that the POST request from swagger-ui is not arriving on the server. An undocumented response is returned from the server although the response code is 200.  This can be seen on the second screenshot.
When disabling https on the reverse proxy, the request arrives on the server correctly and response code is 200.

In my java spring application, I've implemented the proposed solution which are described in  https://springdoc.org/faq.html :  How can I deploy springdoc-openapi-ui behind a reverse proxy?

But it didn't solve my proble.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What protocol do you expect it to use?

Comment: I would like Swagger to use no protocol at all.   So, instead of http:domain-name.com/email/...     I would like to have swagger send  domain-name.com/email/...

Comment: That is not how that works. Protocol is essential for sending the request, because that is how two remote computers (and everything in between) are able to understand what "language" is being spoken to them. The more I hear from you, the more I think this is some kind of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What do you actually want to achieve with this?

Comment: I've added more information at my question which should clarify why I would like to remove the http protocol.

Comment: After you "remove http protocol", what's curl supposed to use? HTTPS? TCP? UDP?

Answer (score -1):

I managed to find how to tell swagger to make the request when pressing the excecute button
In application.yaml, you have to add the following:

swagger:
url: "https://www.example.com.com/aa"